# Can you securely pass credentials from a Flash player to Wowza server?

Tags: security, ldap, video-streaming, credentials, wowza

We would like to require authentication against an LDAP directory for accessing streaming video content from our Wowza Flash server. The credentials would preferably be entered via the Flash player itself.

Wowza forum posts suggest using examples of MySQL database authentication backend code as a starting point for developing an LDAP auth backend. And examples exist for modifying an existing Flash player to challenge the user for credentials on play. But all examples I've found show the credentials being passed as query string parameters in the connect string, ex:

`netconnection.connect("rtmp://[wowza-address]/[app-name]?user1&pass1");`

[This article](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?17122-RTMP-Authentication-client-support) suggests a much more complicated solution to avoid passing credentials in the clear, involving authenticating before streaming, setting a cookie that is specially formulated for reauthentication, grabbing the cookie in the Flash player and passing it to Wowza.

Has anyone seen a solution like this that would pass the credentials for LDAP authentication over a secure connection?

Answer (score 0):

Setup SSL for you Wowza server and change your URIs to read

```
rtmpe://....
```

then you can use the method you described. Anything you try without SSL is vulnerable to man in the middle attacks.